# How to handle large sized oracle databases in a windows server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, database-size, windows-server

My Production database is having 188 GB size. The server handling the db is having C Drive with a space of 250 GB.

My database is growing rapidly.I don't think this database is having much size compared to other production databases. I can't simply increase the size of my C drive according to increase of my production db.

Can anyone suggest me the professional way of handling large databases with more than 300 GB size.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific? Whats is the problem? If your db needs to grow that much then you will need more disk space. If you cant store the data, then you need to identify what is causing the growth, and implement some kind of archiving, purging, compression or aggregation to restrict the growth.

Comment: @Peter : I'm having only 250 GB sized C Drive in my windows server. I think it's not good to increase the size of C drive further more since its having all the programs files, configuration files etc. Can you please suggest me the methods a DBA should follow if they have to handle large db's like 400 and 500 GB's.

Comment: Ideally you should have your db/data on a seperate disk. Add another hard drive and move the database.